# Correct way to express "'worthy of falling in love for"

Tags: prepositions

Please evaluate this sentence for its correctness. I'm concerned about the use of *of* in front of *falling*.

> However, you're utterly off in your assessment about failing in love for someone else. I haven't **found anyone worthy of falling for**, and I will not compromise my feelings to just try.

Comment: typo, I believe you meant "falling in love" not "failing in love." Also *assessment of* sounds better than *assessment about* to my native english speaking ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "fall for someone", but the parallel phrase is not "fall in love for someone", it is "fall in love *with* someone". The text "haven't found anyone worthy of falling for" is awkward, but acceptable English. The text "you're utterly off in your assessment about falling in love for someone else" is incorrect in context since you fall in love "with" someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the couple quibbles I had with the preamble, noted in my comment, I believe the phrase **found anyone worthy of falling for** sounds fine in the context presented.

You wrote about *falling in love* in your first sentence, so the phrase seems unambiguous and understandable to me.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> I haven't found anyone **worth falling
>   for**, and I will not compromise my
>   feelings to just try.

or

> I haven't found anyone **worthy of my
>   affection**, and I will not compromise
>   my feelings to just try.